# What is an efficient way to divide an array by a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Just wondering, what is the most efficient way to divide an array by a scalar? I can clearly loop over it, but efficiency is paramount in my case.

**Common trivial way:**

```
var array_2 = []
var array_1 = [original_data
var divisor = my_scalar
for(var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++){
            array_2.push(array[i]/divisor)
         }
```

Any trick I can use (or a new approach altogether)?

Comment: `var array_2 = array_1.map(i => i / divisor);`

Comment: cool trying it right away

Comment: @tymeJV: What makes you think a bunch of function calls will be more efficient than a `for` loop? (The difference in efficiency is ***extraordinarily*** unlikely to matter, mind...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I didnt say more efficient - I mainly focused on the "new approach all together" part of the question.

Comment: Note that your common trivial way could be more efficient (depending on which JavaScript engine you're talking about): `array_2[i] = array[i] / divisor` (not `push`).

Comment: @tymeJV: It's just both the title and text emphasize efficiency...

Comment: Pre-allocate the `array_2` and then use @T.J.Crowder's solution. Some implementations are optimized for homogeneous arrays. `var array_2 = new Array(original.length)`

Comment: @squint: You have to be careful doing that, since arrays aren't really arrays. IIRC, some years back I checked, and some engines preferred what you did there, and others preferred that you didn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Interesting. IIRC Chrome has optimized for this, but not sure about others.

Comment: This answer on [SIMD mathematics](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34693609/) describes a possibly more efficient method but it seems to not be widely supported. Other than that, all the solutions provided, whether using `map` or just a loop will be generally the same in efficiency.

Comment: @JustinHellreich: Nice! I was wondering if there were some optimizations that would use SIMD but didn't realize there was an actual API defined for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've said you want the *most efficient* way. Fairly sure what you're doing is close, but you want assignment rather than `push`, and in at least some JavaScript engines (V8 for instance, in the Chromium browsers), if you tell the `Array` constructor an initial length, they'll pre-allocate backing storage (even though the array starts with no elements in it):

```
var array_2 = Array(array.length);
for(var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++){
    array_2[i] = array[i] / divisor;
}
```

Having said that: The difference between that and `map` is going to be *very very very very very very* small and it's an exceptionally rare use case where it would matter. Whereas `map` is clear, simple, short...

Comment: frankly overwhelmed by the quickness and precision of the answers! will try both.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map` for that:

```
var newData = data.map(function(item) { return item/scalar } )
```

Comment: Which is a *very very very very very very very very* tiny bit **less** efficient, rather than more.

Answer (score 2):

```
const numbers = [350,451,758,456,999];
const dividedNum = num => num/7;
const output1 = numbers.map(dividedNum);
console.log(output1)
```