# How to calculate relative frequency of array elements using Ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array with repeating values, and I want to get the relative frequency (i.e., proportions) for each repeating value.

It seems natural to me to treat this as a 2-step procedure:

1. *count* the occurrences of each value; and
2. divide that count by the *length* of the original array.

To accomplish the first step we can use `R.countBy()` from `ramda.js`:

```js
const R = require("ramda")

const myLetters = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
const counted = R.countBy(R.identity)(myLetters)
counted // => gives {"a": 4, "b": 2, "c": 4}
```

Now the second step would be to divide `counted` by the length of `myLetters`:

```js
counted / R.length(myLetters) // obviously this doesn't work because it's not mapped
```

I'm a bit lost with how to map this correctly. My current clunky solution that I dislike:

```js
// 1. manually calculate the length and store to a variable
const nvals = R.length(myLetters)

// 2. create a custom division function
const divide_by_length = (x) => R.divide(x, nvals)

// 3. map custom function to `counted`
R.map(divide_by_length, counted) // gives {"a": 0.4, "b": 0.2, "c": 0.4}
```

Although this works, there's gotta be a more straightforward way with `ramda` to get from `counted` to `{"a": 0.4, "b": 0.2, "c": 0.4}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much like the approach from Ori Drori, using the fact that `ap (f, g) //~> (x) => f (x) (g (x))`.  (`chain` used for functions is the related `chain (f, g) //~> (x) => f (g (x)) (x)`.)

My initial thought was similar, using instead `lift`, which lifts a function that operates on values up to become a one that operates on *containers* of those values.  When the containers are functions, it operates something like `lift (f) (g, h) //~> (x) => f (g (x), h (x))`, although it's more generic, as `lift (f)` is variadic, as are the functions supplied to it and therefore also the function it generates, e.g.  `lift (f) (g, h, i, j) //~> (a, b, c) => f (g (a, b, c), h (a, b, c), i (a, b, c), j (a, b, c))`

So, very similarly, I wrote:

```js
const frequencies = lift (map) (
  pipe (length, flip (divide)),
  countBy (identity)
) 

const myLetters = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]

console .log (frequencies (myLetters))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {lift, map, pipe, length, flip, divide, countBy, identity} = R </script>
```

Nonetheless, it's not clear to me that a point-free approach offers any benefit here.  I'm not sure which I prefer, but this non-point-free Ramda is about as readable to my mind:

```js
const frequencies = (letters, total = letters.length) => 
  map (n => n / total) (countBy (identity) (letters) )


const myLetters = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]

console .log (frequencies (myLetters))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {lift, map, pipe, length, flip, divide, countBy, identity} = R </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the results of counting the items in the array, with the length of the array.

You can use `R.ap` as the S combinator by supplying it with 2  functions. The S combinator signature is `S = (f, g) => x => f(x)(g(x))`, where `f` and `g` are functions.

In your case:

f - Create a map curried with divide by the length

g - Create an object of counts

```js
const { ap, pipe, length, divide, __, map, countBy, identity } = R

const fn = ap(
  pipe(length, divide(__), map), // curry a map by divide by length
  countBy(identity), // create the counts
)

const myLetters = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]

const counted = fn(myLetters)

console.log(counted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Scott's answer (2nd solution) caused some pennies to drop for me.

If we define two helper functions preemptively for counting and for dividing:

```js
const myCount = R.countBy(R.identity);
const myDivideBy = (divisor, arr) => R.map(elem => elem / divisor); // I was missing this part
```

Then we could do:

```js
const calcFreq = (arr) => {
    return R.pipe(myCount, myDivideBy(arr.length))(arr)
}
```

Which is exactly the 2-step procedure I imagined from the beginning: first count, then divide.

```js
calcFreq(myLetters) // gives {"a": 0.4, "b": 0.2, "c": 0.4}
```

---

A relevant post: [javascript: efficient way to divide an array by a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584479/6105259)