# Is there a JavaScript equivalent of rubys "#{}" sequences?

Tags: javascript, ruby

Is there a better way to build strings in JavaScript than doing string concatination?

It would make my code cleaner if I could do something like ruby where you can expand variables in a string instead of doing lots of "foo" + bar + "baz".

Answer (score 7):

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
  var args = arguments;
  return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
    return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
      ? args[number]
      : match
    ;
  });
};


console.log("{0} bar {1}.".format("foo","baz"));
```

Will produce:

"foo bar baz"

Comment: Ideally that'd replace `#{...}` to avoid mangling strings that might contain curly braces. For instance, a JavaScript code snippet.

Comment: no problem, no matter, this just search for {number} and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

[Chris Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110164/chris-nielsen) has provided a pure-JavaScript solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408373/512904):

```
String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
    return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
        function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
        }
    );
};

alert("I'm {age} years old!".supplant({ age: 29 }));
alert("The {a} says {n}, {n}, {n}!".supplant({ a: 'cow', n: 'moo' }));
```

---

You could also use CoffeScript, which is a language that compiles to JavaScript. [It supports string interpolation](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#strings):

```
author = "Wittgenstein"
quote  = "A picture is a fact. -- #{ author }"
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry guys but all this is not very the ruby way, here is a basic p equivalent, sorry for the eval, that surely can be done better..
if you just want the concatenation, just replace the document.write by return in the first solution

```
function p(str){
  document.write(str.replace(/#{(\w)}/g, function(match, s){return eval(s)})+"<br>");
}

String.prototype.p = function() {
  return this.replace(/#{(\w)}/g, function(match, s){return eval(s)})+"<br>";
};


var f="foo", b="bar"
p("#{f} #{b}")
document.write("#{f} #{b}".p());

=> foo bar
=> foo bar
```

EDIT: i added a prototype version, had some difficulties with that one

Answer (score 0):

```
var myStr = [];

myStr.push('something')

console.log(myStr.join(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with *lots* of strings then using an array where you `push` the string parts and at the end `join` them (with an empty string as delimiter) seems to be the most efficient across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there a JavaScript equivalent of rubys `“#{}”` sequences?"*

With respect to an *equivalent*, no. JavaScript natively does not have string interpolation. Though you could use a function to replicate it to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

[pylover's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144470/105570) will give you something *like* what you want.

You might also look into [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), which is a nice language that compiles to JavaScript and has string interpolation, among other (perhaps *too* many) features.

Answer (score 0):

It is called syntactic sugar.

```
var a = 2;
var b = 4;
var c = "together";

var text = `Add ${a*b} elements ${c}.`;
console.log(text)

// "Add 8 elements together." (515,988,604 op/sec)
```

vs.

```
var text = "Add" + " " + a*b + " " + "elements" + " " + c + ".";
console.log(text)

// "Add 8 elements together." (511,188,184 op/sec 0.73% slower)
```

First method is faster and better to read.

Performance tested here: [JSPerf string test](https://jsperf.com/speed-string-concat/1)