# prototype function prints itself instead of the result

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was answering a question here [Is there a JavaScript equivalent of rubys "#{}" sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144407/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-of-rubys-sequences/10147398#10147398) when i run in a problem with javascript prototype. I wanted to provide an alternative way of the first working function which gives a ruby way of printing, formatting and concatenating strings. Why is the normal function working and the prototype function not ?

```
<script>
function p(str){
  document.write(str.replace(/#{(\w)}/g, function(match, s){return eval(s)})+"<br>");
}

String.prototype.p = function() {
  return this.replace(/#{(\w)}/g, function(match, s){return eval(s)})+"<br>";
};


var f="foo", b="bar"
p("#{f} #{b}")
document.write("#{f} #{b}".p);

</script>
```

this gives

```
foo bar
function () { return this.replace(/#{(\w)}/g, function(match, s){return eval(s)})+"
"; }
```

the first line is correct, it is the concatenated string, the second line is the function itself that is printed, not the result..

Comment: is there anyone who knows how to avoid the eval here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"#{f} #{b}".p` refers to the function itself (String.p), because "#{f} #{b}" is a string.

You want `"#{f} #{b}".p()` for it to print foo bar.

Comment: of course ! stupid of me, i'm already too accustomed to ruby i guess, thanks