# Javascript html canvas variable as color alpha channel

Tags: javascript, html, variables

how can i do the following:

```
  alpha = alpha + 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,153,255,alpha)';
  ctx.stroke();
```

i am trying to get the variable `alpha` as the alpha channel of the color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to do variable interpolation in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/best-way-to-do-variable-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,153,255,' + alpha + ')';
```