# Pass Text or String or Query in URL - Use contents for dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm inquiring as to how to send text with a URL so it can be used in the destination. I've searched everywhere, I'm not sure my terminology is correct so I can't find much.

I want to append a user's name to a URL, e. g. `www.yourwebsite.com/post?name=John`.

When they click on the URL and the data is passed, is there a way I can pass the data into a dynamic HTML element?

E. g. `<h1>Hello, [name]</h1>` resulting in `<h1>Hello, John</h1>`

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? That would help us narrow it down a bit more!

Comment: maybe look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: I think what you need is a templating system: http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/. Other wise the terminlogy you are looking for is probably string interpolation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

I was going to append a Mailchimp Merge tag from an email: 

www.yourwebsite.compost?name=*|FNAME|*

Which doesn't give me a heap of functionality. I would then decide on how to build my page to pick up the *|FNAME|* and dynamically change elements on the page.