# TypeScript - Angular: Multiline string

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm an Angular 2 beginner and I've written this piece of code in my `dev/app.component.ts`:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h3 (click)="onSelect()"> {{contact.firstName}} {{content.lastName}}</h3>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    public contact = {firstName:"Max", lastName:"Brown", phone:"3456732", email:"max88@gmail.com"};

    public showDetail = false;
    onSelect() {
        this.showDetail=true;
    }
}
```

It works, when I go to the browser "Max Brown is displayed".

Now, I want to write the template part on different lines like this:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h3 (click)="onSelect()">
    {{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}}<h3>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    public contact = {firstName:"Max", lastName:"Brown", phone:"3456732", email:"max88@gmail.com"};

    public showDetail = false;
    onSelect() {
        this.showDetail=true;
    }
}
```

But I get this error in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 334, accepted):

Wrap the text in `` ` `` (backticks) instead of single quotes `'`, then it can span multiple lines.

```
var myString = `abc
def
ghi`;
```

Comment: it works at my place....but why is it not possible with the usual '' like in every other language? for example JS itself...

Comment: Seems you can use normal quotes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript. Backticks also allow interpolation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: how can I ignore spaces and new lines?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Why would you add them in the first place if you don't want them. I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm guessing @SunilGarg wants to add line breaks to the string so it looks good in code, but doesn't want the extra whitespace in the string itself.

Comment: That would be the opposite of what my answer is about. I think that would require `'a b c' + 'd e f'`

Comment: How to bind variable in it?

Comment: @VinitSingh I'd expect https://stackoverflow.com/a/45399981/217408 to work here as well.

Comment: This has the problem that from the second line there must not be any indentation which may look awkward in deeply nested code.

Comment: @dominik that shouldn't be a big problem. It's usually better to make properly named constants for such values anyway and then only use the name in the code (deeply nested or not)

Answer (score 24):

the accepted answer works only if we want \n added in our string , if we just want content to be on newline without adding \n in the long string , please add \ at the end of every line like this

```
string firstName = `this is line 1 \
and this is line 2 => yet "new line" are not \
included because they were escaped with a "\"`;

console.assert(firstName == 'this is line 1 and this is line 2 => yet "new line" are not included because they were escaped with a "\"'); // true
```

Note - make sure you are not adding any tabs and spaces in the beginning of the next(second in the example) line

Answer (score 9):

```js
const multiLineString = [
  "I wish",
  "there were a better way",
  "to do this!",
].join(" ");
```

Comment: This is the cleanest looking solution for building xpath selectors in my code. **Note:** *the `join` method defaults to separating strings with a comma `','`.* You probably want to use `.join("")` .

Comment: Or, for strings that naturally split on spaces, `.join(" ")`

Answer (score -4):

What about this? This would work around the empty spaces in the new lines. But could be a bit unreadable and have performance impacts.

```js
    let myString =
      `multi${""
      }line${""
      }string`;
```

Comment: That looks completely horrible and unnecessarily complicated.