# How to perform string interpolation in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, string-interpolation

C# uses string interpolation

```
int value = 100;
Console.WriteLine($"The size is {value}.");
```

Output:

> The size is 100.

How to do the same thing in TypeScript?

Answer (score 538, accepted):

In JavaScript you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals are literals delimited with backticks (<kbd>`</kbd>)

```
let value = 100;
console.log(`The size is ${ value }`);
```

Comment: any polyfill for typescript like it's available for babel?

Comment: @lawphotog polyfill for what? this is supported in typescript.

Answer (score 125):

Just use special `` ` ``

```
var lyrics = 'Never gonna give you up';
var html = `<div>${lyrics}</div>`;
```

Comment: yes, notice it's the special ``, not a `'`.

Comment: Gives syntax error on IE

Comment: I can't believe I got rickrolled here.

Comment: @Ygalbel:can you tell me how to iterate array with ${arrayData}?

Comment: @KapilSoni check join() function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @Ygalbel its not working in my case

Comment: i wonder who in the world came with this fancy idea!

Answer (score 10):

### It can be done with the *backtick* character: `

Pay attention this is NOT an apostrophe, nor a quote.

### Where to find it on keyboard?

Most probably you're on a **QWERTY** keyboard, so you'll find it JUST below the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in the top left corner:

[image]

In case you're using a special keyboard, you can check this [exhaustive list](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows) to find the backtick.

### Finally this is the code:

```js
const value = 100;
console.log(`The size is ${value}.`);
```

(Valid in both JavaScript and TypeScript)