# How to create template strings in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create some string literals for my code in typescript on the firebase cloud functions platform. I am using VS code as my code editor.

I have looked across the internet and have gotten the same answer (shown below), which doesn't seem to be working. This shouldn't be too complicated

```
const currentUser = "Johnny appleseed"
console.log('The current user is ${currentUserID}')
```

I want the log to say 'The current user is Johnny appleseed' but the code doesn't compile because the variable currentUser is never read from. I would prefer a solution that doesn't include string concatenation as it would be a pain to code.

Comment: You need to use `\`(Backticks)` not `'`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399951/how-to-make-string-interpolation-in-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use back ticks (`), not single quotation marks ('), to use template literals:

```js
const a = 'hi';
console.log('${a}');
console.log(`${a}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ` (and the right variable name):

```
console.log(`The current user is ${currentUser}`)
```