# message = 'Hello ${name}' doesn't replace the name parameter in the message string immediately

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot make working the basic typescript feature that I see written everywhere over the Internet, that says that :

```js
var a = "Bob"  
var message = 'Hello ${a}'
```

would see a `console.log(message)` print "Hello Bob".

When I attempt this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'etude';

  constructor() {
    console.log('Démarrage environnement ' + environment.nom_environnement + ' spark: ' + environment.spark_url + ' backend: ' + environment.backend_url);

    const a = 'Démarrage environnement ${environment.nom_environnement} spark: ${environment.spark_url} backend: ${environment.backend_url}';
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

My console logs are showing that:

```
Démarrage environnement dev spark: http://localhost:9090 backend: http://localhost:9091 main.js:1:598971
Démarrage environnement ${environment.nom_environnement} spark: ${environment.spark_url} backend: ${environment.backend_url}
```

Whatever I try `let a` or `var a` instead of `const a`.

Reading over the Internet, the transformation should had happened immediately?

Comment: try to use ` instead of '

Comment: @AntonMarinenko I don't understand your answer, sorry.

Comment: just see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform string interpolation in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399951/how-to-perform-string-interpolation-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use string interpolation `` and you are using single quotes ''

Answer (score 1):

Use `` instead of ""

```
var a = "Bob"
var message = `Hello ${a}`
```