# How to pass in variable within string field in Typscript

Tags: html, css, typescript

I am trying to show different background images depending on an image id:

```js
var url = "/lectures/" + id +"/thumbnail.jpg";
...
style={{
          backgroundImage: "url({url})",
        }}
...
```

For example, if the id was 1, I would have `backgroundImage: "url('/lectures/1/thumbnail.jpg')"` I have tried this, and the image displays correctly. However, I want to display a different image depending on the id. It seems that using `{}` does not work since the field itself (backgroundImage) takes in a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform string interpolation in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399951/how-to-perform-string-interpolation-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there, but you're not properly concatenating the `url` variable within the `style` object. When you use curly braces `{}` within JSX, you're indicating that you want to embed JavaScript expressions within the JSX code. In your case, you need to ensure that the `url` variable is properly evaluated and inserted into the `backgroundImage` property.

Here's the correct way to do it:

```
var url = "/lectures/" + id + "/thumbnail.jpg";

style={{
  backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
}}
```

In the code above, I've used template literals (denoted by backticks) to embed the `url` variable within the `backgroundImage` property. This way, the actual value of `url` will be inserted into the URL string, and it will correctly display the different images depending on the `id`.

So, for example, if `id` is 1, the generated style will be:

```
style={{
  backgroundImage: "url(/lectures/1/thumbnail.jpg)",
}}
```

And if `id` is 2, it will be:

```
style={{
  background-image: "url(/lectures/2/thumbnail.jpg)",
}}
```

And so on, adapting to the different values of `id`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = "/lectures/" + id + "/thumbnail.jpg";

// Inside your JSX component
<div
  className="your-container-class"
  style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(${url})`, // Use backticks to interpolate the url variable
  }}
>
  {/* Your content */}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have accessed the variable is incorrect. Try it like this

style={{
backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,// Use backticks to interpolate the url variable

}}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).