# Javascript format strings with parameters

Tags: javascript, string

I know this question has been asked before, but other questions I saw were 5 years old. How can I format a string like this in modern Javascript ?

```
var x = str('My name is %x %y', 'john', 'walker');
```

Comment: That linked duplicate is *more* than 5 years old.

Comment: [Some documentation on "modern" JavaScript approaches.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format Has newer answers including template formate from ES6

Comment: Even a 40 years old well-written script can nicely do this. You don't need anything "modern" for manipulating strings.

Comment: @Vohuman ES2015 has a feature explicitly for this purpose (template literals).

Comment: Yes, I know that feature. The point was something else man.

Comment: The system works by new answers being posted for old questions whenever new techniques become available, [just like in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24850933/502381). It's not reasonable to post duplicate questions asking for new solutions every couple of years.

Comment: @Juhana agreed of course. Venerable old questions and their venerable old answers are fine, but nothing clearly directs new users to scroll down looking for new answers describing new facilities stuck at the bottom with scant upvotes.

Comment: (I acknowledge that in this case the template answer is #2 on the page.)