# AngularJS ngTranscluded, angular.noop, and Interpolation VS expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not clear about few concepts in AnguarJS like-

[Refrence](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng) (Official doc is bit confusing for these concepts.)

> When should we use "**ngTranscluded**"?
>
> What will be the case when we would need to create a function which performs no operation using "**angular.noop**"?
>
> In what scenario we should use **interpolation** and in what scenario **expression**?

It would be great, If somebody make me clear with the small examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to use simple terms

ngTransclude - If you want to push html code directly to the directive from outside of directive.

angular.noop - Suppose there is a function which accept a callback. Before calling of callback inside function you are doing some calculations. Now, if you want to execute those calculation but you do not have callback then you may use angular.noop.

```
function func (callback) {
    // Do some calculations

    callback();
}
func(function() {});
func(angular.noop);
```

Check this for interpolation -
[How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)