# Convert String (30-jul-2016) into Date(2016-07-30) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to convert string in date format.

My String format is **30-Jul-2016** And want to convert into **2016-07-30**. Only using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date('30-Jul-2016'.split('-').join(' ')),
    dFormated = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d.getDate();

console.log(dFormated);
```

Comment: var d = new Date('30-Jul-2016') returns invalid date

Comment: Thanks @KeyurShah.. Updated answer

Comment: Yes it works after you edited and added split and join.

Answer (score 1):

To be as dynamic as possible I advise to implement first Douglas Crockford's supplant function, and assign it to String Object's prototype ([How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript/1408373#1408373)). Here's how you do it:

```
String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
    return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
        function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
        }
    );
};
```

After that, you can implement something like this:

```
function changeFormat(from, to){
    var months = [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ];
    var date = new Date(from);
    return to.supplant({
        YYYY: date.getFullYear(),
        MMM: months[date.getMonth()],
        MM: date.getMonth()+1 > 9 ? date.getMonth()+1 : '0'+parseInt(date.getMonth()+1),
        DD: date.getDate() > 9 ? date.getDate() : '0' + parseInt(date.getDate())
    })
}
```

And this is how it would work:

```
changeFormat("30-Jul-2016","{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD}") // 2016-07-30
```

Example:

```js
String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
    return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
        function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
        }
    );
};

function changeFormat(from, to){
    var months = [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ];
    var date = new Date(from);
    return to.supplant({
        YYYY: date.getFullYear(),
        MMM: months[date.getMonth()],
        MM: date.getMonth()+1 > 9 ? date.getMonth()+1 : '0'+parseInt(date.getMonth()+1),
        DD: date.getDate() > 9 ? date.getDate() : '0' + parseInt(date.getDate())
    })
}

console.log(changeFormat("30-Jul-2016","{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a library, like Moment, the best way would be to keep an array of months to get the numerical values *(there's no guarantee every browser will parse that date)*, and then just split the string and parse it

```js
var months = [
  'Jan',
  'Feb',
  'Mar',
  'Apr',
  'May',
  'Jun',
  'Jul',
  'Aug',
  'Sep',
  'Oct',
  'Nov',
  'Dec'
];

function pad(x) {return x < 10 ? '0' + x : x}; // zero padding

var str   = "30-Jul-2016";
var parts = str.split('-');
var date  = new Date(parts[2], months.indexOf(parts[1]), parts[0]);

// now you can output whatever

var new_date = date.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(date.getDate());

document.body.innerHTML = new_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
function formatDate(string) {
  var date = new Date(string),
      dd = date.getDate(),
      mm = date.getMonth() + 1,
      yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  dd = dd < 10 ? '0' + dd : dd;
  mm = mm < 10 ? '0' + mm : mm;

  return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
}

console.log(formatDate('30-Jul-2016')); // 2016-07-30
```

Comment: var date = new Date(string) return invalid date

Comment: In your case it returns a valid Date object. "new Date('30-Jul-2016')" // Sat Jul 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var date = '30-Jul-2016';
date = date.split('-').join(' ');
var d = new Date(date);
alert(d.getFullYear() + '-'+(d.getMonth()+1) +'-'+ d.getDate());
console.log(d.getFullYear() + '-'+(d.getMonth()+1) +'-'+ d.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var date = '30-Jul-2016';
date = date.split('-').join(' ');
var d = new Date(date);
    dd = d.getDate();
      mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
      yyyy = d.getFullYear();

  dd = dd < 10 ? '0' + dd : dd;
  mm = mm < 10 ? '0' + mm : mm;
alert(yyyy + '-'+mm +'-'+ dd);
```