# Can't get String.prototype working in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to implement a function from an [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408373)

```
String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
     return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
         function (a, b) {
             var r = o[b];
             return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
         }
     );
 };
```

I've been trying to put this in a factory like this

```
app.factory('Helpers', function() {
  abc = function (o) {
    return supplant(o);
  }

  abc.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
    return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
        function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
        }
    );
  };

return abc;
});
```

I have used 'Helpers' in my controller, but keep getting errors like
"I'm {age} years old!".abc is not a function

I need to access the function abc() just like shown in the answer like

```
 alert("I'm {age} years old!".supplant({ age: 29 }));
 alert("The {a} says {n}, {n}, {n}!".supplant({ a: 'cow', n: 'moo' }));
```

Comment: What does `app.factory` do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how things work before copy and paste code by hoping it will magically work...

In the example, the `String.prototype` is used to **extend** the **default** JavaScript String object (whatever surrounded by quotes is a String object), so after the following declaration:

```
String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
     return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
         function (a, b) {
             var r = o[b];
             return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
         }
     );
 };
```

all **strings** in your code can invoke the method `supplant()` (in addition to the existing ones like `toUppercase()`, `toLowerCase()`...).

What you did in the angular factory is meaningless, you are not extending JavaScript's **String** object that way, but creating a brand new "type", so obviously by declaring:

```
"a string".supplant()
```

the interpreter complains about it since that method does not exist (by default JavaScript's String interface does not implement a method called `supplant`).

Anyway, since you are using angular, it already provides services for interpolation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

So, inject that service in your controllers and use it, in this way:

```
$interpolate(stringToInterpolate)(contextScopeForInterpolation);
```