# Changing input value field that has interpolation

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, interpolation

I'm trying to reset a value when you click a button by simply setting the .val() with JQuery. The weirdest thing is happening- my code is ONLY working for the state dropdown but not the other inputs, which have their values set inline with SWIG interpolation like so:

```
<input type="text" class="moving-input form-control" id="first-name-search" value="{{search.firstName}}">
```

When this button is clicked:

```
<button type="reset" class="results-form-link" id="perform-new-search">Perform a New Search</button>
```

It should run this code:

```
$('#perform-new-search').click(function() {
    $('#first-name-search').val('hello');
    $('#last-name-search').val('');
    $('#results-states option:selected').val('Select State');
})
```

What's weird is if I try to run $('#first-name-search').val('hello'); in the console directly in the browser it works but it doesn't work when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#perform-new-search').click(function() {

    $('#first-name-search').val('hello');
    $('#last-name-search').val('');
    $('#results-states option:selected').val('Select State');
})
```

Seems like it's working,

check https://jsfiddle.net/aLLrku6r/

Comment: Right it should work but something about the interpolation on the html input value itself is making it not work. (value="{{search.firstName}}")

Comment: this should be helpful - [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript