# how to replace all string having special characters with other string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to replace all ***[$dummyTest$]*** with other text eg. ***realtext***

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ***[$dummyTest$]***, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel augue laoreet, consectetur felis a ***[$dummyTest$]***, laoreet sem. Ut quis sapien tincidunt, consectetur diam aliquam, ultrices nisi ***[$dummyTest$]***. Ut bibendum augue odio, eget imperdiet sapien maximus at.

**Output :**
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ***realText***, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel augue laoreet, consectetur felis a ***realText***, laoreet sem. Ut quis sapien tincidunt, consectetur diam aliquam, ultrices nisi ***realText***. Ut bibendum augue odio, eget imperdiet sapien maximus at.

Comment: What is your use case? Have you considered using a template engine instead?

Comment: it's client request
i am using this keyword [$identity$] as identity, so that i can replace this keyword with real data.
example [$Name$] = "Some Name", [$Address$] = "Some Address" ets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass callback to `String#replace` method

```js
var before = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [$dummyTest$], consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel augue laoreet, consectetur felis a [$name$], laoreet sem. Ut quis sapien tincidunt, consectetur diam aliquam, ultrices nisi [$dummyTest$]. Ut bibendum augue odio, eget imperdiet sapien maximus at."

var texts = {
"[$dummyTest$]": "TEST",
"[$name$]": "SOME NAME"
}

var after = before.replace(/\[\$\w*\$\]/g, function(str){return texts[str]});

console.log(after);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var str = oldStr.replace(/\[\$\w*\$\]/g, id);
```

Which will replace all occurences of `[$someVarible$]` with whatever string is in id.

If you want to replace a specific variable you could do:

```
 var str = oldStr.replace(/\[\$myVar\$\]/g, myVar);
```

So in your specific example.

```js
var orgString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [$dummyTest$], consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel augue laoreet, consectetur felis a [$dummyTest$], laoreet sem. Ut quis sapien tincidunt, consectetur diam aliquam, ultrices nisi [$dummyTest$]. Ut bibendum augue odio, eget imperdiet sapien maximus at."

var editedString = orgString.replace(/\[\$dummyTest\$\]/g, 'realText');

console.log(editedString);
```

Comment: i have different different keyword.
every key having some data and want to replace each keyword with data

Comment: Updated my answer with what you need to do for that if you want to use regular expressions. Another way to go is http://stackoverflow.com/a/1408373/5897779 :)
Here they define a function that builds the regex needed for replacing substrings in quite a neat fasion.