# How do I return an object value inside an if statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I make the line inside the if statement work?

```
const player1 = {
    name: "Ashley",
    color: "purple",
    isTurn: true,
    play: function() {
        if (this.isTrue) {
            return `this["name"] is now playing`;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Comment: By using `return`. But I suspect you're actually asking something else.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect the code to do, and if you now are getting any erroneous output, that too. The return statement is itself completely valid.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the string with this:

```
return `${this["name"]} is now playing`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make the property as isTrue or make the if statement variable check 'isTurn'.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, the if statement won't be hit as `isTrue` isn't a vaiable in `player1`.

However:

```
const player1 = {
    name: "Ashley",
    color: "purple",
    isTurn: true,
    isTrue: true, // Do you need this?
    play: function() {
        if (this.isTrue) { // Or should this be "inTurn"?
            console.log(this.name + " is now playing");
            return this.name + " is now playing";
        }
    }
};

player1.play();
```

You can see this running here: https://jsfiddle.net/ohfu2kn6/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just referring to `isTrue` when you meant to use the property `isTurn` in your if statement.

```
const player1 = {
    name: "Ashley",
    color: "purple",
    isTurn: true,
    play: function () {
        if (this.isTurn) {
            return this.name + ' is now playing';
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const player1 = {
name: "Ashley",
color: "purple",
isTurn: true,
play: function() {
    if (this.isTrue) {
        return this.name +" is now playing";
    }
  }
};
```