# how to put dynamic data in ngx-toastr?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

After login i want show a toaster as Welcome to logged username.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408289)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.toastr.success('Welcome to '+authenticUser.user.firstName,'Success')
```

or

```
this.toastr.success(`Welcome to ${authenticUser.user.firstName}`,'Success');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular or any programming lanuage, it's advised to use the back-tick for string concatenation.

```
this.toastr.success(`Welcome to ${authenticUser.user.firstName}`,'Success');
```

Comment: "any programming language"... ahhh, No. Even if you are really meaning JavaScript, or some library on top of JavaScript, then you still need to consider what environments (e.g. browsers) [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility) are available in (e.g. not in IE). Obviously, that's not a concern if you are cross-compiling into compatible JavaScript.

Comment: Yes agree. we have polyfills for IE too. Also angular CLI will convert to ES5 while performing build.

Comment: Well, I was really trying to point out that saying "any programming language" is *way* to broad. Are you *really* trying to say that you should use back-ticks in C, C++, Java, Forth, Ada, Prolog, Pascal, FORTRAN 77, etc.?

Comment: Ok, Let me correct it. It should be used in JS Programming.