# How to substitute a variable in a template string?

Tags: javascript, object, string-literals

A function which has 2 arguments:

1. First argument will have string - 'hello ${val}'
2. Second argument will be an object - {'val':'world'}

I need to write a solution where the first argument will access the property of the second argument's object and print its value in the first argument's string.

```
 function PropertyAccess('hello ${val}', {val:'world'}){

       //returns   "Hello World"
  }
```

Comment: That is not even a function for starters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your updated question, what I think you really want is a function that will accept a template and an object of values to replace with. Here's a working example.

```js
function PropertyAccess(template, values) {
  for (key in values) {
    template = template.replace('${' + key + '}', values[key])
  }
  
  return template;
}

console.log(PropertyAccess('hello ${val}', {val: 'world'}))
```