# How to show expressions in a browser? (React, VS Code)

Tags: reactjs

In VS Code for React project I try to show expressions, like that example -  ${res.status} where status is variable, but instead of the variable itself a browser shows me a text ${res.status}.  So it does not interpret the variable. 
Any ideas why it's happening?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvMYP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `"` use the back tick `

e.g.

```
"${res.status}" // wrong

`${res.status}` // correct
```

Comment: @GlebKrylov In the photo you just posted, you are using a single quote, not a back-tick.

Comment: Thank you Vencovsky, I put Single quote instead of a backtick