# How to enter a variable in a string in node.js/discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot in NodeJS using discord.js module and I want to send a predefined message in the same channel where a user sends a particular text command.
eg.

````
const token = 'xyz';
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content === '!hi') {
        message.channel.send('Hello ${message.author}!');
    };
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is now connected');

    //  client.channels.find(x => x.name === 'test').send('Hello I\'m now connected.');
});

client.login(token);```

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content === '!hi') {
        message.channel.send('Hello ${message.author}!');    }});
````

I expect the output to be `Hello @discordusername!` but instead, I'm getting `Hello ${message.author}!`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string interpolation in javascript use backticks instead of single quotes.
Ex:

```js
`Hello ${message.author}!`
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`message.channel.send('Hello ${message.author}!');`

with this:

`` message.channel.send(`Hello ${message.author}!`); ``

Answer (score 1):

```
message.channel.send(`Hello <@${message.author.tag}>!`)
```

Comment: What's the benefit to including `.tag` property and `<@ … >` wrapper, as opposed to the otherwise identical syntax proposed in [@Gorgan-Stoyanov's answer from last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58672023/3025856)? Is one more reliable? Does this fix a bug? Or is it just a stylistic preference?