# How to use props in react css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-props

Below is the part of code of my React App:

```
<span 
  value={this.props.range}
  style={{width:"{this.props.range}px"}}
  className="range"
></span>
```

I want to use the value from the props and want to set into style.
But I am not getting how to set it.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try template strings like this:

```
<span 
  value={this.props.range}
  style={{width:`${this.props.range}px`}}
  className="range"
></span>
```