# How to use JXS within html elements' attributes' double quotes as we use in PHP?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So in php if we want to refer to a source of an image, we can do it like this

```
<img src="images/<?php $imageName; ">" />
```

But in JSX of react, we can only do like

```
<img src={image.path} />
```

But since I have only stored the name of the image, I need to do something like this

```
<img src="images/{image.name}" />
```

I do know that image.name is a string rather than a variable as in PHP. But is there a way to make this write?

NOTE: I cannot create a constant string too since that should be written in this.something.map(smth => "I am wriitng it here")

Comment: What you need is a template string, you can check the accepted answer to this post as an example, or just google "javascript template string": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you, I didn't remember string literals from python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
<img src={`images/${image.name}`} />
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved me!! I will tick this as soon as SOF allows me