# Converting a string to img src

Tags: javascript

```
<label id="lbl"></label>
```

I'm trying to get this image to display based on the variable "a" containing the String of the URL. Can someone help me with the missing steps for this?

```
var a = "https://encrypted.google.com/images/logos/ssl_logo.png";

document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML =  '<img src=a >';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You have `.innerHTML = '<img src=a >';`, which is going to have the `src` attribute set to the literal value `a`. You instead want to add the value of the `a` *variable* to your HTML. Luckily, nowadays string templates make that easy:

```
document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = `<img src="${a}" />`;
```

Inside of "backtick" characters, anything appearing in a `${...}` expression gets evaluated and injected into the string. Notice I also surrounded your `src` attribute value in quotes; although HTML parsers are forgiving, omitting that could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You simply concat the strings.

`document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML =  '<img src="' + a +'" \>';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `img` element with the `src` of the value of `a` and `append` it to the `label`:

```js
var a = "https://encrypted.google.com/images/logos/ssl_logo.png";
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = a;
document.getElementById("lbl").appendChild(img);
```

```html
<label id="lbl"></label>
```

However, you can fix your code by using [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var a = "https://encrypted.google.com/images/logos/ssl_logo.png";
document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML =  `<img src=${a}>`;
```

```html
<label id="lbl"></label>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should interpolation strings. `<img src=${a} >` instead of '';