# Undefined variable in jquery's ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a relatively simple code, I am annding event listeners in a loop, but the loop variable is not available when mapping the results.

```js
for (let index = 0; index < 2; ++index) {
    $("#id" + index).on("keyup", function () {

        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://some-url.com",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#div' + index).append(
                        $.map(data, function (myData, index) {
                            return '<a href="#" onclick="selectId(index, myData.id);"> Click me </a>'
                        }).join());
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

The result is:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined`

Edit: if I just use myData.id for example, everything works like a charm
Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: When do you get that result?

Comment: because `'<a href="#" onclick="selectId(index, myData.id);"> Click me </a>'` generates a string with no reference to index. When rendered, it is looking for a global variable `index`

Comment: `"selectId(index, myData.id)"` -> `"selectId(" + index + ", " + myData.id + ")"` assuming `id` is an integer.  Or use string interpolation https://stackoverflow.com/a/35984254/2181514

Comment: if I just use myData.id for example, everything works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You are generating **strings** of HTML with embedded JS.  The JS won't be evaluated until it is inserted in the document. That's a different scope with no `index` or `myData` variables.

Generate a jQuery object instead. And if you don't want to link anywhere, don't use a link!

```
 function (myData, index) {
     const $button = $("<button />")
     $button.text("Click me");
     $button.on("click", () => selectId(index, myData.id));
     return $button;
 }
```

(And don't `join` the array into a string, just append the array of jQuery elements).

Comment: if I just use myData.id for example, everything works like a charm