# Why does not show template literals in under api? its working as a string why? react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[https://love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/getPercentage?fname=**${fname}**&sname=**${sname}*](https://love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/getPercentage?fname=**$%7Bfname%7D**&sname=**$%7Bsname%7D*)*

Why does not show template literals under API? It's working as a string why? react-native
can anyone explain why it's not showing as a template literals?

sorry, my English is very week.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import DisplayPer from './DisplayPer';

const Body = () => {

    const [fname, setfname] = useState("")
    const [sname, setsname] = useState("")

    const calculate = () => {
        fetch("https://love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/getPercentage?fname=${fname}&sname=${sname}", {
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "x-rapidapi-key": "00298dcae5mshba42f70f49fc1b6p148d95jsn941e18e734e5",
                    "x-rapidapi-host": "love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
    }

    return(
        <View style={styles.bodycontainer}>
         <Text style={styles.bodytext}>Enter Friends Data</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.bodyinput}
                placeholder="Type here!"   
                onChangeText={(event)=> setfname(event)}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.bodyinput}
                placeholder="Type here!" 
                onChangeText={(event)=> setsname(event)}  
            />
            <Button
                onPress={calculate}
                title="Learn More"
                color="#841584"
                accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
            />
            <DisplayPer />
        </View>
    )
}

export default Body;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Comment: You need to use backticks `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Url` with

```
`https://love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/getPercentage?fname=${fname}&sname=${sname}`
```