# Postman variable into string

Tags: javascript, postman, chai

I feel kinda dumb asking this question bcs I might be missing something super easy but.. I have a collection of requests in Postman.

I have a collection variable `test_model_id` which is `888`.

What I'm trying to achieve is simply putting the model_id variable into the string in `resp_data` line. I feel like I tried everything lol.

```
var model_id = parseInt(pm.collectionVariables.get("test_model_id"));

pm.test("Test_response_model_creation", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.text();
    var resp_data = JSON.stringify({"detail":"Model {{model_id}} created","HTTPStatusCode":200});
    pm.expect(jsonData).to.eql(resp_data);
});
```

Getting

```
... to deeply equal '{"detail":"Model {{model_id}} created","HTTPStatusCode":200}'
```

Comment: `detail: "Model " + model_id + " created"` or `detail: \`Model ${model_id} created\``

Comment: string manipulation should do it: `"detail": "Model ${model_id} created"`

Comment: This `"Model ${model_id} created"` is what I was trying and it didn't work. At `"Model " + model_id + " created"` I was a little scared it's gonna break the JSON format but it works. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using template laterals?

```
var resp_data = JSON.stringify({"detail":`Model ${model_id}` created","HTTPStatusCode":200});
```

Comment: Sadly I didn't work with JS too much so I totally forgot about these. Thanks!

Comment: Please check if the question is a duplicate before posting an answer.