# How to add ID dynamically in a axios call react?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to add dynamic id to axios call method patch

axios. patch('classrooms/dynamic id here? Api _ key=9345c'. I tried ${id} but it gives an error id not defined

function postData(){

```
  axios.patch(`classrooms/${id}?api_key=${API_KEY}`,`subject=${change}`).then((res)=>
      console.log(res.data)
      
  ).catch((err)=> console.log(err));
```

}

I want to use this function onClick event so if I tried to define id using const postData() wont work . Any way to add Id dynamically?

Comment: need to use backticks for string interpolation: `axios.patch(\`classrooms/${id}?Api _ key=9345c\`)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Comment: yes I used backtick still getting an error id is not defined

Comment: Are you calling this from a web browser? can you use the developer console to see what your network request looks like?

Comment: function postData(){
     
      axios.patch(`classrooms/${id}?api_key=${API_KEY}`,`subject=${change}`).then((res)=>
          console.log(res.data)
          
      ).catch((err)=> console.log(err));
}  I want to pass this function onClick to update an api.

Comment: if i add a specific id it works but i need it to be dynamic

Comment: So it sounds like your `id` variable might be undefined. We need a lot more context (i.e., where and how `id` is defined` and where this request is executed to help

Comment: actually its an api  system to allocate subjects to classrooms and students to classes. so what i want to do is , i need to assign a subject to a classroom, above mentioned is the link of classroom where i want to update.

Answer (score 0):

did you try backticks ?

```js
axios.patch(`classrooms/${id}?Api_key=9345c`)
```

this should work

Comment: tried backtick get an error id not defined.