# I'm trying to use Javascript Fetch rest API in spring boot project by catogeryId

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, rest

Hi im trying to get rest api data on  html page by javascript fetch but i cant be able to fetch url categoryId can anyone help me out.
Ill be so thank full of them.[this is my Html page where i fetching my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxJW0.png)

[This is my rest controller from where i m getting my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDAzo.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so[. Please add code to the question as text rather than as pictures of code.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As im already fetch my data and in that data i have my catogeryId so i just take it out from that in this way onclick="productBrandDataById('+data[i].catogeryId+')">'
Then i just fetch my data with this catogeryId like this fetch('/api/get_productc/'+catagoryId)
then ill use it.

Answer (score -1):

What error do you get?

I guess you have `categoryId` defined somewhere, so you should try something like this:

```
fetch(`/api/get_productc/${categoryId}`).then(...)
```

Be aware that there is a backtick around ( ` ) and $ sign before categoryId.

Comment: i difine catogery id at my controller