# Place variables inside JSON string in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, variables, replace

I wonder if it's possible to place variables into a JSON string value.

Some example: (file.json)

```
{
  "type": "description",
  "description": "${this.name} is ${this.age} years old. ${this.name}'s favorite color is ${this.favColor}"
}
```

Then in React:

```
data = require("file.json);
name = "John";
age = 20;
favColor = "blue";
```

render function...

```
render() {
  return() {
    <p>{this.data.description}</p>
  }
}
```

Any way to do something like this? The goal is to replace the variables automatically.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but you will have to do a manual string find & replace. You can find how to do this pretty quickly.

Comment: This isn't possible, but you can write a `Person` class, initialize it using the JSON data, then make `description` a function that fills in the data.

Comment: I wanted to avoid find&replace, I thought there is a way to automatically replace vars like in php.

Comment: find and replace can be done automatically if you write a dedicated function for it. How much more automatic can it get?

Comment: @ChrisG this was just an example. In my case the description is totally different for every object so it must be contained in the JSON

Comment: @MauriceNino Yes I will go that way. I just thought there is a way to replace it automatically.

Comment: As already said, that **is** automatic. If you want to achieve something else, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a manual string find & replace. Something like the following answer will be ok: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408373/9150652

This could then look something like the following in your React Component:

```
// Your JSON data as string
const json = `{
  "type": "description",
  "description": "{name} is {age} years old. {name}'s favorite color is {favColor}"
}`

// method to find and replace interpolate values
const interpolate = (str, values) => {
  return str.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
      (a, b) => {
          const r = values[b];
          return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
      }
  );
};

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const values = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 27,
    favColor: 'red'
  };

  // Interpolate before parsing the JSON!
  const parsedJson = JSON.parse(interpolate(json, values));

  // Now you can use the object with the correct values filled in
  return <p>{parsedJson.description}</p>;
}
```

> If you use Class components, you could even try passing in `this` instead of `values` and use local values, similar to how you described it in your question
> Should (maybe) work out of the box aswell.

Comment: I wrote my find&replace function. Thank you anyway.