# I got an invalid image when I fetch it. Why that problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, axios, fetch

I try the api using the postman and it is ok. the problem is when I try to fetch the image file to be displayed in the front, it becomes invalid image. Do everything but not show the image

```
function App() {
 
    const [singleFile, setSingleFile] = useState([]);
    const [multipleFile, setMultipleFile] = useState([]);

const getSingleFile = async () => {
    try {
      const {data} = await axios.get("users/getSingleFile");
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  const getSingleFileList = async () => {
    try {
        const filelist = await getSingleFile();
        setSingleFile(filelist);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
        getSingleFileList();

  }, []);


    return ( 

        <div>
            <div>
                <Fotos getSingle={() => getSingleFileList} />
            </div>

            {singleFile.map((file, index)=>
                <img src={ "http://localhost:5000/${file.filePath}"} alt="img"/>
                )}

        </div>
        )

};

export default App;
```

Comment: Well what does `users/getSingleFile` respond with and why are you treating it like an array if it's named **single file**?

Comment: Sorry I am new to programming. the users/getSingleFile respond with the image correctly, I save it in mongo db , it is ok too. but it return to the front page, not showing the image, the code executes, but It only show the format of the image, do not show the content

Comment: ```router.get("/getSingleFile", async (req,res, next) => {
 try {
  const files = await User.find();
  res.status(200).send(files)
 } catch(error) {
  res.status(400).send(error.message);
 }
});```

Comment: I think the problem is the src={ "http://localhost:5000/${file.filePath}"}     When I try to use backticks, instead "" , the localhost becomes a comment

Comment: GET http://localhost:5000/$%7Bfile.filePath%7D 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @phil Sorry I did'nt understand cause programming in new for me. as I told you the code is ok, it fetch the images, but don't show it correct

Comment: Yes, it fetches the images but **what EXACTLY** is the response format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this, replace '' by ``:

```
<img src={ `http://localhost:5000/${file.filePath}`} alt="img"/>
```

Comment: I try to use backticks but it transform into a comment because the // in localhost

Comment: @Kerpenrodrigorosademiranda this answer is correct. You must be doing something different if it doesn't work for you

Comment: @Phil IT is working now, despite it appearing a comment, I dont know why it didnt work before, maybe I didnt reload or save correctly, but some images is working now. Thanks so much

Comment: @Soufiane Boutahil thanks so much

Comment: Can you please select the answer as correct?