# How to override the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am using a drop-down using JSTL (on the JSP page), this drop-down contains multiple records.
[Code SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NfKv.png)

[Original drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxZ1W.png)

EXPECTED RESULT: There should be new "Value" on drop down and that value is not part of drop down.

```
<select name="salution" class="form-select" id="salution" required>
  <c:forEach items="${salution}" var="sol">
    <option value="${sol.lovVal}">${sol.lovName}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I want to show a single value on that drop-down which already holds too many values.
I am using Ajax to override a single value on the same drop-down which already holds multiple values.

```
 var someValue="some value";                  
                $('#salution')
                        .find('option')
                        .remove()
                        .end()
                        .append('<option value="${sol.lovVal}" >${someValue}</option>');
```

also tried this one, I have to just override ${someValue}.

```
var someValue="some value";                  
                $('#salution')
                        .find('option')
                        .remove()
                        .end()
                        .append('<option value="1" >${someValue}</option>');
```

Any solution?

Comment: You want to remove a *single* `<option>`?   Do you know anything about that option?  Th selected one?  Change `.find("option")` to `.find("option:selected")` so you only remove the selected one

Comment: I want to remove all values from the drop-down and show a new value. (And want to make it as read-only field)

I have seen this .find('option') on some blog. I don't have any idea about that why we even use that.

Comment: I have used .find("option:selected") one, but it took value based on ID which are already part of dropdown.

In my case, I have to set a value which is completely new.

Comment: If will be easy to answer if you'll provide initial HTML of `<select>` and expected output of `<select>`

Comment: Please, Review the QUESTION now.

Comment: `.find("option").remove()` removes all the options.     What is your code doing that you don't want it do / not doing that you do want it to do?

Comment: Off Topic: always use a free-form box for salutation unless you're going to code off it (eg "if user is Dr then do...") which is very unlikely.   There will *always* be another valid salutation that you've haven't included and it's very frustrating for the user to not be able to put in their real, earned salutation.

Comment: `.append('<option value="1" >' + someValue + '</option>');` or use a backtick `.append(\`<option value="1" >${someValue}</option>\`);`

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript

Comment: Freedomn-m:
Oooh , you saved my life.
Thanks for this. 

`.append('<option value="1" >' + someValue + '</option>');`

This line is working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a single value on drop-down, which already holds multiple values.

Freedom-m helped in comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m

You have to use this line of code.

```
.append('<option value="1" >' + someValue + '</option>');
```