# Access CSS variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why can't I do this? Or how can i do this?

```
/* this does not work and I want to achieve something like this */
el.style.setProperty("--member-clr", var('--server-clr'));

/* only below works */
el.style.setProperty("--member-clr", 'black')
```

CSS:

```
main {
   --server-clr: linear-gradient(blah,blah)
}
```

I tried above and simply what I need to work does not work(it's illegal I get it so what is my best option?)

Comment: Typo: Quotes go around the *whole* value: `el.style.setProperty("--member-clr", 'var(--server-clr)')`

Comment: When you tried to set the CSS value `black`- did you then use `black` in your code, or did you use `'black'`? The latter, and for a good reason, because you meant that as _text_, and not as reference to a JavaScript variable named `black`. And `var('--server-clr')` is _not_ a JavaScript function either ...

Comment: @Quentin  btw, how can I make this work?

        cover.style.setProperty("--cover-clr", "var(o.Background)");

I tried both   "var(${o.Background})"
or   `"var(${o.Background})"`

Comment: @anonymousinternet — You now seem to have an entirely different question about [string interpolation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript).

Comment: sorry @Quentin  you are right..sorry about that and I just figured it out. thank you!